# Regarding JSON API of Wordpress

Tags: android, json, wordpress

How to include more than one tags in JSON Response that I got after sending a GET request??

I tried using this:
http://example.com/api/get_recent_posts/?json=get_posts&include=title

This fetches me the wordpress posts and ids. How to include excerpts along with this?

Comment: The link is not working. Paste example into question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOP! Found the solution! Just had to separate the tags with commas!
This worked for me:

http://example.com/?json=get_posts&include=title,excerpt